# неправильный ответ на двух тестах задачи о размере компоненты связности в графе. Поиск в глубину

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x, графы, dfs

Условие задачи:

> Дан неориентированный невзвешенный граф. Для него вам необходимо найти количество вершин, лежащих в одной компоненте связности с данной вершиной (считая эту вершину).

Граф представлен в виде матрицы смежности.

Сразу же написал решение через поиск в глубину:

```
def dfs(v):
    visited.append(v)

    for i in range(n):
        if graph[v][i] == 1 and i not in visited:
            dfs(i)


n, s = map(int, input().split())
graph = [list(map(int, input().split())) for x in range(n)]

visited = []
dfs(s)

print(len(visited))
```

1. Запускаем функцию `dfs` на стартовой вершине
2. Добавляем ее в список посещенных
3. Пробегаем по каждой вершине
4. Проверяем соединена ли она с текущей и есть ли она в списке посещенных
5. Если все ок, то запускаем в ней `dfs`
6. В конце считаем кол-во элементов в списке `visited` и выводим его

Программа выдает неправильный ответ на двух тестах. [Ссылка на проверяющую систему](http://informatics.mccme.ru/mod/statements/view.php?id=256)

ЧЯДНТ?
*(Я видел другие реализации, но хотел узнать в чем ошибка именно в моем коде)*

Comment: дайте ссыль на соревнование

Comment: @hedgehogues, http://informatics.mccme.ru/mod/statements/view.php?id=256

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Номер заданной вершины `s` задаётся в интервале `1 ≤ s ≤ n`, то есть нумерция с единицы.

(Ошибку можно обнаружить, например, на графе из одной вершины)

Comment: то есть первый вызов надо делать так:
`dfs(s-1)`